# Linux using lapack library

Tags: linux, makefile, lapack

I have an error making a code project because of what I believe is a missing routine from lapack:

```
HomographyInit.cc:(.text+0x385): undefined reference to `dgesvd_'
```

I think I need to add lapack library somehow to my Makefile. Here is part of my Makefile:

```
CC = g++
COMPILEFLAGS = -I MY_CUSTOM_INCLUDE_PATH -D_LINUX -D_REENTRANT -Wall  -O3 -march=nocona -msse3
LINKFLAGS = -L MY_CUSTOM_LINK_PATH -lGVars3 -lcvd
```

I tried doing the following to no avail:

```
CC = g++
COMPILEFLAGS = -I MY_CUSTOM_INCLUDE_PATH -D_LINUX -D_REENTRANT -Wall  -O3 -march=nocona -msse3
LINKFLAGS = -L MY_CUSTOM_LINK_PATH -lGVars3 -lcvd **-llapack**
```

Result:

```
make
...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I add lapack to my project? I am pretty sure I installed it correctly, though would be willing to double-check that somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like liblapack isn't in the path that ld can find. I would suggest two things:

1. Establish a symbolic link manually. It is possible (and sometimes common) that ld cannot recognize `liblapack.so.3gf` or `liblapack.so.3.0.1` or so are essentially `liblapack.so`. You can set up a link by `ln -s liblapack.so.3gf liblapack.so`
2. Install `liblapack-dev` package instead if you're using ubuntu or debian repos. For some unclear reasons, `liblapack3gf` is not the same as `liblapack-dev`. I am not sure if in any circumstances, both will do or not do the same thing.

I think the first item should be able to resolve your problem (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

On my computer the dynamic library is in /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.4.1 and contains the requested symbol:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.4.1 | grep dgesvd
0000000000189200 T dgesvd_
```

So I would guess that the place where your lapack is installed is not in the linker search path. You should add the flag `-L/path/to/the/lapackdir` to LINKFLAGS

Comment: Hmm, I don't even have the /usr/lib64/ folder (even though I'm on a 64-bit machine). I'm looking for liblapack.so right now.

Comment: I have: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf. Should I put this in the Makefile somehow?

Comment: `LINKFLAGS = -L MY_CUSTOM_LINK_PATH -lGVars3 -lcvd -L/usr/lib` did not work, though I wouldn't be surprised if I made a syntax error here (not too sure what I'm doing tbh)

Comment: You should try ``LINKFLAGS = -L MY_CUSTOM_LINK_PATH -lGVars3 -lcvd -L/usr/lib -llapack``. However, I don't really expect it to work. And please don't say "did not work" but report the problem. By the way, isn't there any missing $ in MY_CUSTOM_LINK_PATH ?

Comment: Just tried that, getting this error again: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack`

Comment: One last check before I run out if idea: what is the answer of ``ldd  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf`` ? Sorry for the typo !

Comment: `ldd: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: No such file or directory`

Comment: `ldd /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff48fff000)
 libblas.so.3gf => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf (0x00007f3ec3f84000)
 libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f3ec3c6d000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3ec3972000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3ec375c000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3ec339f000)
 libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f3ec3168000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3ec4e2f000)
`

Comment: Sorry I've no more idea !

Comment: No worries thanks for trying. I will work on re-installing LAPACK I guess.